# How to auto trigger 'ESC' key after page load using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I understand 'ESC' key on the keyboard is a not a modifier key. I want to know how can I use Javascript to auto hit 'ESC' after the page on the browser finishes loading. I am working on a chrome extension to automatically take care of this.

I have tried multiple sources to understand this but unable to find a working solution.

So using Chrome Extension, 
I want to stop a webpage from redirecting to another page. Hence, using 'ESC' key with keycode = 27 should help using Javascript. Basically once the webpage is loaded completely it should trigger 'ESC' functionality.

Comment: ESC is not a modifier key, modifier keys are Shift, Ctrl, Alt... What are you actually *trying* to do?

Comment: There is a webpage, I want to stop it from redirecting to another page. Hence, using 'ESC' key with keycode = 27 should help using javascript. Basically once the webpage is loaded completely it should trigger 'ESC' functionality.

Comment: Try injecting `window.onbeforeunload = function() {return "Stop!";};`. This will cause an "are you sure you want to leave" confirmation before leaving the page. You can then cancel the redirect with the "Stay" button.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Also, I would like to understand if I can still invoke 'ESC' functionality?

Comment: Triggering an artificial esc keypress programmatically is not the same thing as pressing esc on the keyboard, as far as the browser UI is concerned. (You can't scroll the page by triggering space press or down key press either, for example.) You'll have to find out how the page does the redirection and prevent that specifically.

Answer (score -1):

You can use given code.

```
$(function() {
    var e = $.Event('keypress');
    e.which = 27
    $('item').trigger(e);
});
```

Comment: I am not getting any output in the console using this. I am using it to have a chrome extension.

Comment: You have to replace item with some element's id, on which you want to trigger

Comment: Can you please give an example of this? Thanks.